# In C# how to check if date falls on every 5th day since 1990?

Tags: c#, date, date-arithmetic, days

I need to check if date falls on 5th day of date since Jan 1, 1990.

Dates include:

```
Jan 5, 1990,
Jan 10, 1990,
Jan 15, 1990,
Jan 20, 1990,
Jan 25, 1990,
Jan 30, 1990,
Feb 4, 1990,
Feb 9, 1990,
```

Etc.

The algorithm also has to work in future so I've to be able to check if it's 5th day even if program is run 2 years from now.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Right now I'm iterating and adding 5 days to 1990, but that is a lot of unnecessary looping. If my program is used in 5 years, that's another 5 years of date loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every 5th day since Jan 1,1990:

```
var is5thday=yourdate.Subtract(new DateTime(1990,1,1)).Days % 5 == 0;
```

However, your sample data shows every 5th day since Dec 31, 1989, so:

```
var is5thday=yourdate.Subtract(new DateTime(1990,1,1)).Days % 5 == 4;
```

or

```
var is5thday=yourdate.Subtract(new DateTime(1989,12,31)).Days % 5 == 0;
```

Comment: not all months have same number of days. even if they had this would not work still

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It works fine.  It finds every 5th day.  Not every 5th of the month if that is what you thought he was asking for.

Comment: well thats on Etc part ;) OP should update his answer to state that.

Comment: Jan 1, 1990 - Day 1, Jan 2, 1990 - Day 2, Jan 3, 1990 - Day 3, Jan 4, 1990 - Day 4, **Jan 5, 1990 - Day 5**.

Comment: Jan 1, 1990 is Day 0.  On Jan 1, 1990 it's been 0 days since Jan 1, 1990.

Comment: No, it's the 1st day. I look for every 5th day. So Jan 1, 1990 - 1st day, Jan 2, 1990 - 2nd day, Jan 3, 1990 - 3rd day, Jan 4, 1990 - 4th day, **Jan 5, 1990 - 5th day.** Just like that.

Comment: I hope that makes sense. I'm counting like normal people do from day 1. :)

Comment: Then use the 2nd or 3rd answer I gave.

Answer (score 1):

Sum up the total number of days for the years from 1990.

Use that SUM with modulo 5 `SUM % 5 = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static bool checkDate(DateTime date)
{
    var start = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1);

    return (date - start.Date).Days % 5 == 4;
}
```

Test in Linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    checkDate(new DateTime(1990, 1, 5)).Dump();
    checkDate(new DateTime(1990, 1, 10)).Dump();
    checkDate(new DateTime(1990, 1, 15)).Dump();
    checkDate(new DateTime(1990, 1, 20)).Dump();
    checkDate(new DateTime(1990, 1, 25)).Dump();
    checkDate(new DateTime(1990, 1, 30)).Dump();
    checkDate(new DateTime(1990, 2, 4)).Dump();
    checkDate(new DateTime(1990, 2, 9)).Dump();
}
```

Output:
    True
    True
    True
    True
    True
    True
    True
    True

Comment: I thought so too, but the only difference (for days) is that TotalDays will return a double with the fractional part representing partial days vs Days which is an int.

Comment: @Robert, I stand corrected! I've been misusing TotalDays for years! I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Well, there is a big difference for .Hours and .TotalHours, etc.  It's just since for days, there is no larger unit, they are basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Jan 1, 1990 is Day 0. On Jan 1, 1990 it's been 0 days since Jan 1,
>   1990.

That's is correct, but then your sample dates miss one day:

```
DateTime initialDate = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1);
DateTime sampleDate = new DateTime(1990, 1, 6);
bool isDayOf5 = sampleDate.Subtract(initialDate).Days % 5 == 0;

// returns true
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually looking to count from day 1 and verify every 5th day. So Jan 1, 1990 - 1st day, Jan 2, 1990 - 2nd day, Jan 3, 1990 - 3rd day, Jan 4, 1990 - 4th day, **Jan 5, 1990 - 5th day.**

Comment: That's of course OK - but being _day 1_, 1990-01-01 is not also _day 0_. Thus, you will have to use either of the two last methods provided by @Robert.